# How to draw a tree with an arbitrary number of children?

Tags: graph, tree, draw, graph-algorithm

I'm struggling with coming up with an algorithm which allows me to draw a tree like data structure where each node can have 0..n children.
The issue for me is, I don't know how far apart I have to place nodes so that children won't overlap.

In this example the "d"s are children of "b" and the "g"s are children of "e" and they overlap on the x-axis when I just spread children out evenly above its parent given the total width of the tree.

```
              g g g g g g g g   (9 nodes)
              \ \ \ \ | / / /
d d d d d d d d d     e         (10 nodes)
\ \ \ \ / / / / /     |
       b              c         (2 nodes)
           \      /
              a                 (1 node)
```

The nodes are not ordered in any way. So it's actually more like a graph which has to look like a tree.

Comment: Can you specify how you define *overlap*, please? In your example, would you like to have 10 columns or rather 18 (= 9 g's + 9d's)?

Comment: I'd like to have 18. So that the x coordinates of all the "g"s are greater than those of the "d"s.

Comment: Yes, your answer put me on the right track. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine the spacing, I suggest an algorithm which consists of three main steps. We will use the language of [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory): The tree to be draw consists of [*nodes*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(graph_theory)) `a`, `b`, `c`, ...

- **Step 1.** We start with determining the *layer* for each node which measures the *distance* to the *root node* `a`.  We assume  that you have prepared your tree as [*adjacency list*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) which mainly a table with 2 columns, start-node and end-node of each [*edge*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphEdge.html). In the given example, we have `a - b`, `a - c`, `b - d1`, ... `b - d9`, `c - e`, `e - g1`, ...`e - g9`. Note the node naming scheme, which explicitly resolves the multiplicity of `d` and `g`. We end up with a table like this:

```
# node: layer
a: 0
b: 1
c: 1
d1: 2
d2: 2
...
d9: 2
e: 2
g1: 3
g2: 3
...
g9: 3
```

- **Step 2.** We also have to determine and track the overall number of nodes per layer as well as the number of [*leaf nodes*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/leaf_node) per layer, i.e. nodes without any sucessor. Leaves can be identified easily in the adjacency list as node-identifiers which occur only in the 2nd column, but not in the 1st column. In the given example, layer 0 and 1 are free of leaves, layer 2 has 9 leaves, namely `d1` ... `d9`, and layer 3 has only leaves `e1` ... `e9`. At this stage, we have constructed the following table:

```
# layer: leave nodes, overall nodes, non-leave nodes (in this layer)
0: 0, 1, 1
1: 0, 2, 2
2: 9, 10, 1
3: 9, 0, 0
```

- **Step 3.** Finally, we expand the table which we just created with a column *cumulative leaf count*. All we do is to sum up how many leaf nodes we already encountered:

```
# layer: cumulative nodes
0: 0
1: 0
2: 9
3: 18
```

The result is 18, which is the number of columns needed to display the tree overlap-free.